# How to pass values from lightbox to main page

Tags: php, lightbox

My main application opens an user page. There are New / Edit / Delete buttons on the same page.

I am using Datatables Editor to display records. When I click on New button an lightbox opens up and the datatables editor build-in plugin shows add user template. When this template is submitted a new record is created. The backend has a AUTO_INCREMENT key which I want to be passed back to main page such that I display a message 'User ID : XXXXX has been created'

The issue is that even though I pass it as a session variable the main page which I believe since it is already loaded and cannot be refreshed after lightbox page is submitted - it never receives the updated session variable. As such session variable though set dynamically when user submits lightbox from backend is never seen in main page

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Use ajax to update the session variable?

Comment: Unfortunately Datatables states that we cannot override AJAX success method cause it uses the same to render data back in main page

Comment: can I make another Ajax call on the completion of Datatables Ajax method in Datatables Ajax complete method?